# Concurrent programming with a simple server

Tags: java, multithreading, server

I am creating a simple server that accepts a `int` and returns the value received twice:

```
public class MyServer{

    private static int port = 1234;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            ServerSocket serversock=new ServerSocket(port);
            while(true){
                Socket  socket=serversock.accept();
                new Thread(new MyClass(socket)).start();
            }
        }catch(IOException e){}
        }
    }

    class MyClass implements Runnable{

        Socket socket;

        public MyClass(Socket s){socket = s;}

        public void run(){
            try{
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                int x = in.readInt();
                out.write(2*x);
                socket.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e){}
    }
}
```

My question is about redesigning the code. Are there any weaknesses in the design?
If yes, then what changes would make the code better?

Comment: NEVER catch exceptions and eat them silently, as you are doing: `catch(IOException e){}` At least put `e.printStackTrace();` between the braces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really are planning on creating a thread for each incoming request just use and `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`.  As long as the incoming requests arent very often, this ExecutorService will create a new thread when you submit to it, but if a thread is idle and not being used, the service will reuse the thread instead of creating a new one.

Edit: Here is the example using your code.

```
public class MyServer{

    private static int port = 1234;


    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            final ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
            ServerSocket serversock=new ServerSocket(port);
            while(true){
                Socket  socket=serversock.accept();
                service.submit(new MyClass(socket));
            }
        }catch(IOException e){}
        }
    }

    class MyClass implements Runnable{

        Socket socket;

        public MyClass(Socket s){socket = s;}

        public void run(){
            try{
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                int x = in.readInt();
                out.write(2*x);
                socket.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e){}
    }
}
```

With this you have the possibility of thread reuse.

Answer (score 6):

The ugly part that sticks out is that you are silently ignoring the exceptions... You should do some cleanup and close the sockets at least.

Improving a bit on the performance side, you are starting a new thread to execute a very small task, thus wasting a lot of time to start-up threads. You could instead submit the `Runnable`s to an `ExecutorService`, provided that receiving a number from the client does not depend on user input (otherwise you will block the thread pool if the first few clients don't send anything)

Comment: Thankx for the valuable suggetion
i am new to this, i am implementing     Executerservice 
as

ExecutorService es = newCachedThreadPool();
    es.execute(new Double(socket));

in place of 
    new Thread(new Double(socket)).start();

is this okay!

Comment: @Rex, yes, the cached thread pool creates a number of initial threads and then recycles them when there are new tasks to execute. If you want to specify a fixed number of threads to use you can use newFixedThreadPool();

Comment: @Tudor newCachedThreadPool will actually only create threads on demand.  It will start with 0 threads.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to [Tudor's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/8996/tudor) response, you also shouldn't write infinite loops - that's just silly. For servers that are intended to run for an unknown amount of time (possibly endlessly), I do

```
while (keepServerRunning) {   // where 'keepServerRunning' is a simple boolean variable
  ...
```

...and then use a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) to set the value to `false` which allows the server (and the JVM) to exit normally, without having to kill the task via `kill -9` or a force close.

While it's theoretically possible that a service will run forever, it's just not good practice to pretend like that happens in reality. Clean up after yourself, and provide your apps a simple, clean way to exit normally whenever possible.